# Split Polylines and Count Number of Segments Tool in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, polyline-creation

I recently stumbled upon a tutorial on Esri's website that would split up a polygon or series of polylines (can't remember specifically) but I lost the link!

Is anyone familiar with a tool like this?

There was a very specific diagram that I tried to recreate in photoshop:

[image: splitting into multiple lines and counting]

The result of the operation would be something along the lines of 8 lines being counted from this one shape.

Answer (score 2):

[Split line at vertices](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/split-line-at-vertices.htm) followed by [get count](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/get-count.htm) should do the trick.

[Feature-to-line](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-line.htm) or [Polygon-to-line](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/split-line-at-vertices.htm) may also work, they are subtly different in terms of how they handle intersection line segments.